# ASP.NET MVC Active PDF WebGrabber - How to handle Cutom error pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages, handleerror, webgrabber

We are using webGrabber for PDF generation in asp.net MVC application, when generating pdf some server side errors coming and error pdf files are being generated, can any one suggest how to handle error pages (custom error pages) for third party tools.

Please see this image, this is how pdf is geneated, this is custom error page in our application
  [image]

Comment: assuming these problems generate exceptions, then you can handle them just like any other exception. The fact is comes from some 3rd party library doesn't seem particularly relevant to that. How do you handle exceptions normally? An error-handling action filter (applied globally via FilterConfig) is a pretty common solution.

Comment: @ADyson I want to know can we skip this error handling based on query string, because custom error page is rendering as PDF.

Comment: it would help a great deal if you would show the code which is causing the error, and explain the circumstances in which an error occurs, and also show your current setup with regards and error handling and use of custom error pages. It's hard to understand everything just from a description. It sounds like maybe the PDF renderer is capturing the output from the MVC application no matter what that output is, whether it's the intended output or an error message. From that I'd guess maybe you are suppressing exceptions or something, but I can only guess until you show me.

Comment: @ADyson there is nothing wrong with code, it will throw exceptions some times and we are handling them with HandleErrorAttribute and redirecting to custom error page, when generating pdf same process is happening and error page pdf files are being generated, 
Here I want to know can we **skip this Error handling based on Query String** in Url. Please see attached image for sample error pdf.

Comment: "there is nothing wrong with code"...clearly there is, if it's not working as you intended....   "can we skip this Error handling based on Query String", maybe you can, but surely you don't want to skip the error handling - that's important. Surely you really want to skip the PDF generation and just display the error page properly?